# Why does GetGlyphIndicesW add seemingly non-existent mappings for certain character ranges?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi, truetype

So I am using Windows' [`GetGlyphIndiciesW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getglyphindicesw) to get glyph indices for some symbol fonts I am experimenting with. These fonts provide mappings for characters in the Unicode private use area (around 0xF000), and as far as I'm aware those are the only mappings they have. Yet `GetGlyphIndicesW` always seems to  "add in" mappings from other character codes, particularly around the ASCII range, to some of the glyphs. Some example code utilising Microsoft's "Webdings" font:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HDC device_context = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
    auto font = CreateFont(0, 0, 0, 0, FW_NORMAL, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
        DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
        DEFAULT_QUALITY, DEFAULT_PITCH, L"Webdings");
    auto old_font = SelectObject(device_context, font);

    std::ofstream file("mappings.txt");
    for (WCHAR i = 0; i < 0xF200; ++i) {
        WORD index;
        GetGlyphIndicesW(device_context, &i, 1, &index, GGI_MARK_NONEXISTING_GLYPHS);
        file << "0x" << std::hex << i << ' ';
        if (index == 0xFFFFu) {
            file << "N/A";
        }
        else {
            file << std::dec << index;
        }
        file << '\n';
    }

    SelectObject(device_context, old_font);
    DeleteObject(font);
    DeleteDC(device_context);
}
```

Which simply prints to file each character code from 0 to 0xF1FF and its glyph mapping, if it exists.
As expected, there's a contiguous range from 0xF020 to 0xF0FF mapping to each glyph. But there's also a handful of mappings around 0x2015 (a bit strange), and quite a few from 0 to 0xFF. 0 to 0x1F map to glyph 0, then 0x20 to 0x7E map 3 to 97, then there's a gap of mostly unmapped, and then 0xA2 to 0xFF map 132 to 225.
Yet looking in various font editors there are definitely no such mappings outside 0xF020 to 0xF0FF. And stranger still is that various different symbol fonts, such as "Symbol" and "Wingdings", and even some third-party proprietary ones I've tested, have almost the exact same patterns of extra mappings "added in" by `GetGlyphIndicesW`.

So what's going on?

Comment: Webdings is not a Unicode font and doesn't use the private range, mostly because it harks from 1997 and these glyphs are not defined by the Unicode standard.  It maps character codes [0x21..0xff] to symbol glyphs.  Something that is easy to see with the Charmap.exe applet.

Comment: @HansPassant Hmm... this is interesting... You're right, Character Map definitely shows it starting at 0x21. Yet when using other font programs (I'm looking at [fontdrop.info](https://fontdrop.info/) currently), it definitely shows glyph mappings from 0xF021. Strange. Also Character Map seems to be repeating the font's range? For me it fills out all 0x21 to 0xDD01.

Comment: That might be a font mapper feature, never tried to do that intentionally.  My Win10 version of Charmap.exe shows it starting at 0x21 (pencil symbol) and stopping at 0xff (Windows logo).  Be sure to select the font in the combobox.

Comment: @HansPassant I think it's a glitch/bug. Each time I open it it changes the ending range. In any case, while 0x21 to 0xFF may be the true range of the font, the questions that remains is why it's inconsistent with GetGlyphIndicesW and font editors. Especially GetGlyphIndiciesW, which seems to correctly map the glyphs in the ~0xF020 range, but has chunks of unmapped codes in 0x21 to 0xFF.

Comment: An update: Using GetGlyphIndiciesA on fonts such as Webdings results in a correct mapping in the range 0x21 to 0xFF (and obviously no mapping elsewhere because it's not supported). Using GetGlyphIndiciesW on fonts that are definitely Unicode, such as Arial, results in correct mappings across the whole range, consistent with what font editors show. So it seems that GetGlyphIndiciesW only works as expected for Unicode fonts. Question is 1) why, 2) why do font editors map it differently, and 3) how is one meant to differentiate and handle it programmatically?